# How can I inject data into a class using dependency injection XML?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I'm under the impression that we can inject data into classes using `di.xml` and the `$data` array dependency. I'm struggling with getting it working however. Am I not understanding the concept correctly? Or am I missing some configuration?

Below is my (simplified) code.

`etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="DannyNimmo\Subcategories\Block\ListCategory">
        <arguments>
            <argument xsi:type="array" name="data">
                <item xsi:type="string" name="test">test</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

`Block/ListCategory.php`:

```
<?php

namespace DannyNimmo\Subcategories\Block;

class ListCategory
    extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{

    public function __construct (
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        var_dump($data);
    }

}
```

Edit: I should say that I am seeing an empty array `array(0) { }` as the output.

Comment: Have you tried re-running magento setup:di:compile or deleting the contents of the var/di and var/generation folders?

Comment: @AndrewNoble Yeah, I'm running in developer mode, and have cleared those directories multiple times.

Comment: @DannyNimmo have you got the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your code at the moment to solve your issue but I'd like to add something that can be useful.

DI is intended to pass **injectables**, that are classes that encapsulate some **logic**. DI shouldn't be used to pass data, the so called **newables**.

For example, if you need the data you are trying to inject, you should instead **inject a class that is responsible of retrieving that data**. This kind of classes are called **repositories**. In some circumstances it's better to use **factories**.

You can read more [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2/158099).

Enjoy.

Comment: Are you sure? For example: there are multiple session managers. Each instance use custom session namespace ( like in Magento). Are you think, that we need to hardcode all namespaces in services ( SessionNamespaceProvider for example ) instead of setup namespaces values via di.xml?

Comment: In this case I was wanting to inject via DI for customisability, i.e. data can be easily added by another module. What is your opinion on the purpose of `$data` in this case?

Comment: @danny you can also set data values using layout configuration (attributes tag in block declaration)

Comment: Sorry @Max I don't understand your point. The di.xml is the "default" mapping between an interface declaration (the one you pass to the constructor) and the actual class you want to instantiate. It's ok to use di.xml to change that mapping for session managers that are a perfect example of injectables.

Comment: Hi @DannyNimmo I don't like the idea of passing data via di.xml; so said feel free to use the framework the way you prefer.

Comment: @Alessandro we are talking about the data, which used for setup any services via `di.xml`. By your opinion, we can use only objects for setup services.
But Magento `di.xml` configuration provide broader settings than base "Dependency Injection" concept (for example "plugin", "virtualTypes"). You can setup your models via `di.xml` using many data types, not only objects (string, boolean, array), moreover this possibility is actively used by magento core. Try to find `xsi:type="string|array|boolean"` in core `di.xml` files.

Comment: About question: i think, that author does not need to setup `newable`(product, category, store) in `data`, maybe it is `view_mode`, `column_count`, `container_css_class`, which can be changed by other dependend modules

Comment: i am not adherent of setuping blocks using di.xml, but it is possible. I will remoind, that for setuping `data` can be used `arguments` tag in layout configuration.

Comment: `The di.xml is the "default" mapping between an interface declaration (the one you pass to the constructor) and the actual class you want to instantiate.` not only

Comment: Ok @max, got it, thank you for your explanation.