# Magento2: Difference between Factory and Repository

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, factory, repository, learn-magento

What is the difference between these two objects in magento2? (Factory and Repository) I have seen that they have almost the same methods. What proper use does one have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Different between factory and repository

**Factory definition:**

*Factories are service classes that instantiate non-injectable classes, that is, models that represent a database entity. They create a layer of abstraction between the ObjectManager and business code.*

**Definition of repository:**

*A repository object is responsible for reading and writing your object information to an object store*

See more details at [When Should We Use a Repository and Factory in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2)

Comment: Then, a factory to create a new object and repository to read and write existing objects in database?

Comment: yes, it have that privilege ..

Comment: before yo could load an object using factory but now load method is deprecated