# Which one is the difference between Product and ProductRepository?

Tags: magento2, model

In Magento 2, which one is the difference between `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` and `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository`?

Using both of them, seems they have the same methods, so I don't know when I should use one or the other.

Comment: Take a look https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% deep knowledge of this.

But i am pretty sure that  you should use

> **\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface**

As it can use for both api and model layer

See the magento document:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1//extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html#service-interfaces

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html

[How to implement service contract for a custom module in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2)