# Magento 2: When should we use a ProductRepository, ProductFactory, Product model?

Tags: magento2, model, magento2.3.1, factory, repository

When should we use a ProductRepository, ProductFactory, Product model?

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php

generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductFactory.php
```

Example would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 5):

First, check below links for understanding **Repository pattern**

- https://inchoo.net/magento-2/repository-pattern-in-magento-2/
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html
- https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/

**`ProductRepository.php`** is the main class to get product data. The repository is a design pattern which allows code separation between data retrieval and business logic and Magento 2 use this design pattern.

You can use **Repository** also use for Magento **REST AND SOAP API**  and that main advance of the repository. *Same class use for both API, frontend, admin area for getting a particular entity data like category, Product, etc*.

A `repository` is a part of the **service contracts**. We use service contacts to Implement API point and Service contacts are related with RepositoryInterface and Data interface

Here `Product.php` is Data model class which provide

and `ProductFactory.php` is the Factory class which uses initiate the data class.

Also, check this MSE answer for understanding when you will use Factory and Repository [When Should We Use a Repository and Factory in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2/158098#158098)

From Magento 2.2 version, Magento tried to avoid data using `load()` function of Model class and this `load()` method is a deprecated method.

Comment: But if you see in repository there is also retrieve data by using load method.

like if am taking getById method example there is also data retrieve  using load

Comment: @RutveeSojitra A repository is a new mechanism used by Magento. The main advantage of the repository is API which can be used in any area(admin, frontend, API), while with a model we only use getter and setter. Yes, Magento not updated the direct load model in many files due to backward compatibility.

Comment: @amit-bera could you please let me know where you have seen `load()` function is deprecated?
[Reference Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php)

Comment: Load() of model  class is deprecated.Resource class load()  is NOT deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

**When should USE**

**ProductRepository**

- Product repository is generally used to call data collection of product which is basically call ResourceModel at the end.
- When you call Product Repository it will call resource model and cache that product in repository object so when you call it another time. It will retrieve product data from that cache.
- You can find vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php 
  `public function get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false)`
- You can use it to show product information which doesn't need every time to refresh product data like mobile API, webpage front.

**ProductFactory**

- It's a factory class of Product Model, which is called product model class but on time of `ProductFactory->create()` called.
- It's a factory object you can use it when you need a new object of product every time.

**Product Model**

- Product model is used to interact with the database using its resource object. so for retrieving data purpose use Product Repository cause it will give performance enhancement by it's caching mechanism by the repository.
- And If you need to do any database operation related to save, update then you can use `ProductResourceModel` class which is direct interact to product resource model class.